# Angular Custom element with Material styles are NOT applying when using it in different Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-elements, angular-material-5

I have created angular custom elements by following the blog tutorial .
[link is here](https://notiz.dev/blog/create-a-component-library-for-angular-and-the-web)

I bundled the custom elements into single js and css files and used that js, css files in different angular application imported them in angular json file like the below.
[image]
The element is rendered but materials styles for that element are not applying.
I attached screen please check
[image]